# What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?

Tags: sql, algorithm, recursion, tree, hierarchical-data

Assume you have a flat table that stores an ordered tree hierarchy:

```
Id   Name         ParentId   Order
 1   'Node 1'            0      10
 2   'Node 1.1'          1      10
 3   'Node 2'            0      20
 4   'Node 1.1.1'        2      10
 5   'Node 2.1'          3      10
 6   'Node 1.2'          1      20
```

Here's a diagram, where we have `[id] Name`.  Root node 0 is fictional.

```
                       [0] ROOT
                          /    \ 
              [1] Node 1          [3] Node 2
              /       \                   \
    [2] Node 1.1     [6] Node 1.2      [5] Node 2.1
          /          
 [4] Node 1.1.1
```

What minimalistic approach would you use to output that to HTML (or text, for that matter) as a correctly ordered, correctly indented tree?

Assume further you only have basic data structures (arrays and hashmaps), no fancy objects with parent/children references, no ORM, no framework, just your two hands. The table is represented as a result set, which can be accessed randomly.

Pseudo code or plain English is okay, this is purely a conceptional question.

Bonus question: Is there a fundamentally better way to store a tree structure like this in a RDBMS?

---

**EDITS AND ADDITIONS**

To answer one commenter's ([Mark Bessey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17826/mark-bessey)'s) question: A root node is not necessary, because it is never going to be displayed anyway. ParentId = 0 is the convention to express "these are top level". The Order column defines how nodes with the same parent are going to be sorted.

The "result set" I spoke of can be pictured as an array of hashmaps (to stay in that terminology). For my example was meant to be already there. Some answers go the extra mile and construct it first, but thats okay.

The tree can be arbitrarily deep. Each node can have N children. I did not exactly have a "millions of entries" tree in mind, though.

Don't mistake my choice of node naming ('Node 1.1.1') for something to rely on. The nodes could equally well be called 'Frank' or 'Bob', no naming structure is implied, this was merely to make it readable.

*I have posted my own solution so you guys can pull it to pieces.*

Comment: "no fancy objects with parent/children references" - why not? Creating a basic Node object with .addChild(), .getParent() method's allows you to model the node relationship pretty well.

Comment: Is it a regular (n children where n can be > 2) tree or binary tree (node can have 0, 1 or 2 children)?

Comment: Since you can implement a proper node data structure with a hashmap, there is no real restriction here, just more work.

Comment: ... and that's exactly what you did.

Comment: **Bonus Question Answer**: for those who may have missed this, an answer to the bonus question is ***Transitive Closure Table*** which can be found in the answer by @billkarwin https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/42223

Comment: @dreftymac, Technically, the transitive closure table is denormalized. It's harder to avoid data anomalies than the traditional adjacency list design. But as is typical for a denormalized design, it makes certain types of queries faster.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the candid and balanced description of the trade-offs. I'm going to go ahead and assume you caught me out as someone who read through your excellent write-ups on the topic, and has slowly morphed into a TCT partisan zealot XD. Guilty as charged ^_^.

Comment: **See also:** related answer in the domain of CSharp programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648166/nice-universal-way-to-convert-list-of-items-to-tree

Comment: **See also:** related item in the domain of Ruby programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure

Comment: **See also:** related item in the domain of Javascript programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383869/converting-flat-structure-to-hierarchical

Answer (score 508, accepted):

Now that [MySQL 8.0 supports recursive queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), we can say that [all popular SQL databases support recursive queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause/325243#325243) in standard syntax.

```
WITH RECURSIVE MyTree AS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.* FROM MyTABLE AS m JOIN MyTree AS t ON m.ParentId = t.Id
)
SELECT * FROM MyTree;
```

I tested recursive queries in MySQL 8.0 in my presentation [Recursive Query Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown) in 2017.

Below is my original answer from 2008:

---

There are several ways to store tree-structured data in a relational database.  What you show in your example uses two methods:

- **Adjacency List** (the "parent" column) and
- **Path Enumeration** (the dotted-numbers in your name column).

Another solution is called **Nested Sets**, and it can be stored in the same table too.  Read "[Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202)" by Joe Celko for a lot more information on these designs.

I usually prefer a design called **Closure Table** (aka "Adjacency Relation") for storing tree-structured data.  It requires another table, but then querying trees is pretty easy.

I cover Closure Table in my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) and in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

```
CREATE TABLE ClosureTable (
  ancestor_id   INT NOT NULL REFERENCES FlatTable(id),
  descendant_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES FlatTable(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (ancestor_id, descendant_id)
);
```

Store all paths in the Closure Table, where there is a direct ancestry from one node to another.  Include a row for each node to reference itself.  For example, using the data set you showed in your question:

```
INSERT INTO ClosureTable (ancestor_id, descendant_id) VALUES
  (1,1), (1,2), (1,4), (1,6),
  (2,2), (2,4),
  (3,3), (3,5),
  (4,4),
  (5,5),
  (6,6);
```

Now you can get a tree starting at node 1 like this:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM FlatTable f 
  JOIN ClosureTable a ON (f.id = a.descendant_id)
WHERE a.ancestor_id = 1;
```

The output (in MySQL client) looks like the following:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 | 
|  2 | 
|  4 | 
|  6 | 
+----+
```

In other words, nodes 3 and 5 are excluded, because they're part of a separate hierarchy, not descending from node 1.

---

Re: comment from e-satis about immediate children (or immediate parent).  You can add a "`path_length`" column to the `ClosureTable` to make it easier to query specifically for an immediate child or parent (or any other distance).

```
INSERT INTO ClosureTable (ancestor_id, descendant_id, path_length) VALUES
  (1,1,0), (1,2,1), (1,4,2), (1,6,1),
  (2,2,0), (2,4,1),
  (3,3,0), (3,5,1),
  (4,4,0),
  (5,5,0),
  (6,6,0);
```

Then you can add a term in your search for querying the immediate children of a given node.  These are descendants whose `path_length` is 1.

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM FlatTable f 
  JOIN ClosureTable a ON (f.id = a.descendant_id)
WHERE a.ancestor_id = 1
  AND path_length = 1;

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 | 
|  6 | 
+----+
```

---

Re comment from @ashraf: "How about sorting the whole tree [by name]?"

Here's an example query to return all nodes that are descendants of node 1, join them to the FlatTable that contains other node attributes such as `name`, and sort by the name.

```
SELECT f.name
FROM FlatTable f 
JOIN ClosureTable a ON (f.id = a.descendant_id)
WHERE a.ancestor_id = 1
ORDER BY f.name;
```

---

Re comment from @Nate:

```
SELECT f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.ancestor_id order by b.path_length desc) AS breadcrumbs
FROM FlatTable f 
JOIN ClosureTable a ON (f.id = a.descendant_id) 
JOIN ClosureTable b ON (b.descendant_id = a.descendant_id) 
WHERE a.ancestor_id = 1 
GROUP BY a.descendant_id 
ORDER BY f.name

+------------+-------------+
| name       | breadcrumbs |
+------------+-------------+
| Node 1     | 1           |
| Node 1.1   | 1,2         |
| Node 1.1.1 | 1,2,4       |
| Node 1.2   | 1,6         |
+------------+-------------+
```

---

A user suggested an edit today. SO moderators approved the edit, but I am reversing it.

The edit suggested that the ORDER BY in the last query above should be `ORDER BY b.path_length, f.name`, presumably to make sure the ordering matches the hierarchy. But this doesn't work, because it would order "Node 1.1.1" after "Node 1.2".

If you want the ordering to match the hierarchy in a sensible way, that is possible, but not simply by ordering by the path length. For example, see my answer to [MySQL Closure Table hierarchical database - How to pull information out in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c).

Comment: This is very elegant, thank you. Bonus point awarded. ;-) I see one small drawback though - as it stores the child relation explicitly *and* implicitly, you need to do a lot of careful UPDATEing for even a small shift in the tree structure.

Comment: True, every method of storing tree-structures in a database requires some work, either when creating or updating the tree, or when querying trees and subtrees.  Choose the design based on which you'd like to be simpler:  writing or reading.

Comment: The "parent" design you showed in your question is easy to maintain, and easy to query if you only need immediate parent or immediate child.  But not possible to get a full tree in one query, unless you use proprietary syntax like Oracle's CONNECT BY.

Comment: Very good and usefull trick. I used and enjoyed it. +1, +10 if I could. But there is something you should add that's seems very important to me : you can't identify the first direct children with only a closure table. You need the closure table AND the adjacency list to work together to performs task like adjusting behaviour of a list of item according to the state of the children.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm curious about whether it's possible to sort the entire tree by node *and* by name -- in your example to @ashraf it sorts an entire tree, but it loses the structure. You allude to using a `pathlength` column to assist in sorting, in a [blog post](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html); can you elaborate on that? I might end up doing it in my scripting code, but I'm curious about the possibility of doing it in SQL.

Comment: @Pauld'Aoust, thanks, I've added an example in a comment to my blog to which you linked.

Comment: @BillKarwin Oop, I misunderstood your purpose of `pathlength` for use in sorting -- I thought it was for sorting sibling nodes rather than sorting paths. I was awake at 4:30 this morning figuring out how to sort siblings in a whole tree, and I think I determined that I have to do it in my application code.

Comment: @Pauld'Aoust, right, I haven't found a really elegant way of sorting siblings in any of the various ways of storing hierarchical data.  That's something I'd like to find a solution for.

Comment: @BillKarwin Your answers & presentation on Closure tables are very informative. Other than storage requirements, what is the downside of closure table (in terms of query time/complexity)?

Comment: @buffer, there's a chance to create inconsistencies as you create all the rows for a hierarchy. Adjacency List (`parent_id`) only has one row to express each parent-child relationship, but Closure Table has many.

Comment: @BillKarwin One more thing, are Closure Tables suitable for a graph with multiple paths to any given node (e.g. a category hierarchy where any leaf or non-leaf node may belong to more than one parent)

Comment: @buffer, I have not experimented with that so I can't answer.

Comment: @buffer, as long as the directed graph is acyclic (has no cycles) the closure table approach will work. However, you'll end up having lots more rows in the closure table since the closure table is effectively all of the possible paths from the starting node. 

Trees after all are just a special case of a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: @BillTutt, the problem with representing a DAG this way is that queries can find multiple paths to the same leaf node. That results in nodes being output in the result set redundantly, with multiple different paths. It's even unclear what is the path length to a given node. But this is expected, because many things about a DAG are more complex than a simple tree.

Comment: Good day, i got a question, and is how to migrate from Adjacency List table to a Closure, i means what is the query to do that, because in the examples the insert statement already have ancestor and descendant information and would be amazing know how to map correctly the data from "parent list" to "tree data" using querys.   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @carlosa. Short answer is: you have to write a program. There's no way to do it in a single SQL statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621873/how-can-i-create-a-closure-table-using-data-from-an-adjacency-list

Comment: why do you add (1,1) or (2,2) to ClosureTable?
Is it necessary?

Comment: @Reza, so that if you add a new child node, you can query for all descendants of (1) and those are the ancestors of the new child.

Comment: Doing research on tree based data led me to this post, which in turn lead me to your book.  I don't really work with much advanced SQL, so I've had a hard time knowing whats realistic in terms of how much is feasible/timely in a single query.  I've been toying with your comment SQL structure from the book but mixed in depth field you mention in this post.  Could one fetch 30 top level comments and 2 comment replies both sorted by comment_date in a timely query.  Or would it be better to just query for 30 top level comments sorted by time and then query for sorted sub comments separately?

Comment: What if we want to get the subtrees by value. Like a node with in a subtree has highest value, we want to get that tree first ?

Comment: @Srikan, sure, what's stopping you? Query for the node with the max value, then you have the node id. Then you query for the tree containing that node.

Comment: I guess SQL Server is not a "popular database", because it [doesn't support this standard syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) (no "RECURSIVE", must use "UNION ALL").

Comment: @Noumenon, yes, for some reason unknown to me, Microsoft chose not to use the RECURSIVE keyword, but otherwise they do support recursive CTE syntax.

Comment: @BillKarwin Could you please mention [your Recursive Query Throwdown presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown) in the post? It made me very comfortable with MySQL 8 but it was hard to find.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, thank you, good suggestion. I have added a link.

Comment: @BillKarwin What if we have values as 4 and 5. Can we recursively identify/create the path? So ideally, if 4 and 5 are provided, we should be able to see the same diagram that OP has provided.

Comment: Recursive CTEs are also available in MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: My ClosureTable has data like (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) and I want to be able to retrieve 2,3,4 when I search for 1. I don't have mysql 8 so I don't know anything about recursive queries, but is that the only way to get what I want in a single query? The above answer requires an entry to specifically link the 1 with each of the other numbers and in my situation, that is not practical as there are many many cross-connections.

Answer (score 65):

If you use nested sets (sometimes referred to as Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal) you can extract the entire tree structure or any subtree within it in tree order with a single query, at the cost of inserts being more expensive, as you need to manage columns which describe an in-order path through thee tree structure.

For [django-mptt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/), I used a structure like this:

```
id  parent_id  tree_id  level  lft  rght
--  ---------  -------  -----  ---  ----
 1       null        1      0    1    14
 2          1        1      1    2     7
 3          2        1      2    3     4
 4          2        1      2    5     6
 5          1        1      1    8    13
 6          5        1      2    9    10
 7          5        1      2    11   12
```

Which describes a tree which looks like this (with `id` representing each item):

```
 1
 +-- 2
 |   +-- 3
 |   +-- 4
 |
 +-- 5
     +-- 6
     +-- 7
```

Or, as a nested set diagram which makes it more obvious how the `lft` and `rght` values work:

```
 __________________________________________________________________________
|  Root 1                                                                  |
|   ________________________________    ________________________________   |
|  |  Child 1.1                     |  |  Child 1.2                     |  |
|  |   ___________    ___________   |  |   ___________    ___________   |  |
|  |  |  C 1.1.1  |  |  C 1.1.2  |  |  |  |  C 1.2.1  |  |  C 1.2.2  |  |  |
1  2  3___________4  5___________6  7  8  9___________10 11__________12 13 14
|  |________________________________|  |________________________________|  |
|__________________________________________________________________________|
```

As you can see, to get the entire subtree for a given node, in tree order, you simply have to select all rows which have `lft` and `rght` values between its `lft` and `rght` values. It's also simple to retrieve the tree of ancestors for a given node.

The `level` column is a bit of denormalisation for convenience more than anything and the `tree_id` column allows you to restart the `lft` and `rght` numbering for each top-level node, which reduces the number of columns affected by inserts, moves and deletions, as the `lft` and `rght` columns have to be adjusted accordingly when these operations take place in order to create or close gaps. I made some [development notes](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/source/browse/trunk/NOTES) at the time when I was trying to wrap my head around the queries required for each operation.

In terms of actually working with this data to display a tree, I created a [`tree_item_iterator`](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/source/browse/trunk/mptt/utils.py#29) utility function which, for each node, should give you sufficient information to generate whatever kind of display you want.

More info about MPTT:

- [Trees in SQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20081102031702/http://www.intelligententerprise.com/001020/celko.jhtml) (archive)
- [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: I wish we would stop using abbreviations like `lft`and `rght` for column names, I mean how many characters we didn't have to type? one?!

Comment: It's because 'left' and 'right' are reserved words in SQL

Comment: @meecect that's why just always double quote "EVERYTHING".

Comment: I wonder what is the advantage of the left/right representation over left/size representation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42781302/895245 Left/size seems like it will be simpler to update siblings.

Comment: I found an interesting post that compares the performance of nested sets vs. adjacency lists in Postgres 8: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/24/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-postgresql/ TL;DR: Adjacency sets perform faster at some operations, and when they perform worse, it's by a factor of two.

Answer (score 32):

It's a quite old question, but as it's got many views I think it's worth to present an alternative, and in my opinion very elegant, solution.

In order to read a tree structure you can use **recursive Common Table Expressions** (CTEs). It gives a possibility to fetch whole tree structure at once, have the information about the level of the node, its parent node and order within children of the parent node.

Let me show you how this would work in PostgreSQL 9.1.

1. Create a structure

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tree (
       id int  NOT NULL,
       name varchar(32)  NOT NULL,
       parent_id int  NULL,
       node_order int  NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT tree_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
       CONSTRAINT tree_tree_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
         REFERENCES tree (id) NOT DEFERRABLE
   );


   insert into tree values
     (0, 'ROOT', NULL, 0),
     (1, 'Node 1', 0, 10),
     (2, 'Node 1.1', 1, 10),
     (3, 'Node 2', 0, 20),
     (4, 'Node 1.1.1', 2, 10),
     (5, 'Node 2.1', 3, 10),
     (6, 'Node 1.2', 1, 20);
   ```
2. Write a query

   ```
   WITH RECURSIVE 
   tree_search (id, name, level, parent_id, node_order) AS (
     SELECT 
       id, 
       name,
       0,
       parent_id, 
       1 
     FROM tree
     WHERE parent_id is NULL

     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 
       t.id, 
       t.name,
       ts.level + 1, 
       ts.id, 
       t.node_order 
     FROM tree t, tree_search ts 
     WHERE t.parent_id = ts.id 
   ) 
   SELECT * FROM tree_search 
   WHERE level > 0 
   ORDER BY level, parent_id, node_order;
   ```

Here are the results:

```
     id |    name    | level | parent_id | node_order 
    ----+------------+-------+-----------+------------
      1 | Node 1     |     1 |         0 |         10
      3 | Node 2     |     1 |         0 |         20
      2 | Node 1.1   |     2 |         1 |         10
      6 | Node 1.2   |     2 |         1 |         20
      5 | Node 2.1   |     2 |         3 |         10
      4 | Node 1.1.1 |     3 |         2 |         10
    (6 rows)
```

The tree nodes are ordered by a level of depth. In the final output we would present them in the subsequent lines.

For each level, they are ordered by parent_id and node_order within the parent. This tells us how to present them in the output - link node to the parent in this order.

Having such a structure it wouldn't be difficult to make a really nice presentation in HTML.

Recursive CTEs are available in **PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, MS SQL Server, Oracle and SQLite**.

If you'd like to read more on recursive SQL queries, you can either check the documentation of your favourite DBMS or read my two articles covering this topic:

- [Do It In SQL: Recursive Tree Traversal](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/do-it-in-sql-recursive-tree-traversal)
- [Get to know the power of SQL recursive queries](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/sql-recursive-queries)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach, and how it produces deterministic output with the final ORDER BY (which PostgreSQL 14.5 says is not supported in the recursive query: `error: ORDER BY in a recursive query is not implemented`). Unfortunately though, it produces breadth-first traversal, and the tree representation of a book would need pre-order instead.

Comment: Last 2 links to go "404 - Not found"

Comment: Note that building a whole recursive tree is very expensive if you want to add paging. Because even if you select small part of the tree you should build a whole tree every time anyway

Answer (score 19):

As of Oracle 9i, you can use CONNECT BY.

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', (LEVEL - 1) * 4) || "Name" AS "Name"
FROM (SELECT * FROM TMP_NODE ORDER BY "Order")
CONNECT BY PRIOR "Id" = "ParentId"
START WITH "Id" IN (SELECT "Id" FROM TMP_NODE WHERE "ParentId" = 0)
```

As of SQL Server 2005, you can use a recursive common table expression (CTE).

```
WITH [NodeList] (
  [Id]
  , [ParentId]
  , [Level]
  , [Order]
) AS (
  SELECT [Node].[Id]
    , [Node].[ParentId]
    , 0 AS [Level]
    , CONVERT([varchar](MAX), [Node].[Order]) AS [Order]
  FROM [Node]
  WHERE [Node].[ParentId] = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [Node].[Id]
    , [Node].[ParentId]
    , [NodeList].[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    , [NodeList].[Order] + '|'
      + CONVERT([varchar](MAX), [Node].[Order]) AS [Order]
  FROM [Node]
    INNER JOIN [NodeList] ON [NodeList].[Id] = [Node].[ParentId]
) SELECT REPLICATE(' ', [NodeList].[Level] * 4) + [Node].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [Node]
  INNER JOIN [NodeList] ON [NodeList].[Id] = [Node].[Id]
ORDER BY [NodeList].[Order]
```

Both will output the following results.

```
Name
'Node 1'
'    Node 1.1'
'        Node 1.1.1'
'    Node 1.2'
'Node 2'
'    Node 2.1'
```

Comment: cte can be used in both sqlserver and oracle @Eric Weilnau

Answer (score 10):

Bill's answer is pretty gosh-darned good, this answer adds some things to it which makes me wish SO supported threaded answers.

Anyway I wanted to support the tree structure and the Order property.  I included a single property in each Node called `leftSibling` that does the same thing `Order` is meant to do in the original question (maintain left-to-right order).

```
mysql> desc nodes ;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| leftSibling | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc adjacencies;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| relationId | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| child      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pathLen    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[More detail and SQL code on my blog](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/closure-table-part-deux-nodes-and-adjacencies-a-tree-in-mysql/).

Thanks Bill your answer was helpful in getting started!

Answer (score 8):

There are really good solutions which exploit the internal btree representation of sql indices. This is based on some great research done back around 1998.

Here is an example table (in mysql).

```
CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tw` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pa` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sz` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nc` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tw+sz) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `node_tw_index` (`tw`),
  KEY `node_pa_index` (`pa`),
  KEY `node_nc_index` (`nc`),
  CONSTRAINT `node_pa_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`pa`) REFERENCES `node` (`tw`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The only fields necessary for the tree representation are:

- tw: The Left to Right DFS Pre-order index, where root = 1.
- pa: The reference (using tw) to the parent node, root has null.
- sz: The size of the node's branch including itself.
- nc: is used as syntactic sugar. it is tw+sz and represents the tw of the node's "next child".

Here is an example 24 node population, ordered by tw:

```
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
| id  | name    | tw | pa   | sz   | nc   |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
|   1 | Root    |  1 | NULL |   24 |   25 |
|   2 | A       |  2 |    1 |   14 |   16 |
|   3 | AA      |  3 |    2 |    1 |    4 |
|   4 | AB      |  4 |    2 |    7 |   11 |
|   5 | ABA     |  5 |    4 |    1 |    6 |
|   6 | ABB     |  6 |    4 |    3 |    9 |
|   7 | ABBA    |  7 |    6 |    1 |    8 |
|   8 | ABBB    |  8 |    6 |    1 |    9 |
|   9 | ABC     |  9 |    4 |    2 |   11 |
|  10 | ABCD    | 10 |    9 |    1 |   11 |
|  11 | AC      | 11 |    2 |    4 |   15 |
|  12 | ACA     | 12 |   11 |    2 |   14 |
|  13 | ACAA    | 13 |   12 |    1 |   14 |
|  14 | ACB     | 14 |   11 |    1 |   15 |
|  15 | AD      | 15 |    2 |    1 |   16 |
|  16 | B       | 16 |    1 |    1 |   17 |
|  17 | C       | 17 |    1 |    6 |   23 |
| 359 | C0      | 18 |   17 |    5 |   23 |
| 360 | C1      | 19 |   18 |    4 |   23 |
| 361 | C2(res) | 20 |   19 |    3 |   23 |
| 362 | C3      | 21 |   20 |    2 |   23 |
| 363 | C4      | 22 |   21 |    1 |   23 |
|  18 | D       | 23 |    1 |    1 |   24 |
|  19 | E       | 24 |    1 |    1 |   25 |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
```

Every tree result can be done non-recursively.
For instance, to get a list of ancestors of node at tw='22'

**Ancestors**

```
select anc.* from node me,node anc 
where me.tw=22 and anc.nc >= me.tw and anc.tw <= me.tw 
order by anc.tw;
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
| id  | name    | tw | pa   | sz   | nc   |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
|   1 | Root    |  1 | NULL |   24 |   25 |
|  17 | C       | 17 |    1 |    6 |   23 |
| 359 | C0      | 18 |   17 |    5 |   23 |
| 360 | C1      | 19 |   18 |    4 |   23 |
| 361 | C2(res) | 20 |   19 |    3 |   23 |
| 362 | C3      | 21 |   20 |    2 |   23 |
| 363 | C4      | 22 |   21 |    1 |   23 |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
```

Siblings and children are trivial - just use pa field ordering by tw.

**Descendants**

For example the set (branch) of nodes that are rooted at tw = 17.

```
select des.* from node me,node des 
where me.tw=17 and des.tw < me.nc and des.tw >= me.tw 
order by des.tw;
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
| id  | name    | tw | pa   | sz   | nc   |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
|  17 | C       | 17 |    1 |    6 |   23 |
| 359 | C0      | 18 |   17 |    5 |   23 |
| 360 | C1      | 19 |   18 |    4 |   23 |
| 361 | C2(res) | 20 |   19 |    3 |   23 |
| 362 | C3      | 21 |   20 |    2 |   23 |
| 363 | C4      | 22 |   21 |    1 |   23 |
+-----+---------+----+------+------+------+
```

**Additional Notes**

This methodology is extremely useful for when there are a far greater number of reads than there are inserts or updates.

Because the insertion, movement, or updating of a node in the tree requires the tree to be adjusted, it is necessary to lock the table before commencing with the action.

The insertion/deletion cost is high because the tw index and sz (branch size) values will need to be updated on all the nodes after the insertion point, and for all ancestors respectively.

Branch moving involves moving the tw value of the branch out of range, so it is also necessary to disable foreign key constraints when moving a branch.  There are, essentially four queries required to move a branch:

- Move the branch out of range.
- Close the gap that it left. (the remaining tree is now normalised).
- Open the gap where it will go to.
- Move the branch into it's new position.

**Adjust Tree Queries**

The opening/closing of gaps in the tree is an important sub-function used by create/update/delete methods, so I include it here.

We need two parameters - a flag representing whether or not we are downsizing or upsizing, and the node's tw index. So, for example tw=18 (which has a branch size of 5). Let's assume that we are downsizing (removing tw) - this means that we are using '-' instead of '+' in the updates of the following example.

We first use a (slightly altered) ancestor function to update the sz value.

```
update node me, node anc set anc.sz = anc.sz - me.sz from 
node me, node anc where me.tw=18 
and ((anc.nc >= me.tw and anc.tw < me.pa) or (anc.tw=me.pa));
```

Then we need to adjust the tw for those whose tw is higher than the branch to be removed.

```
update node me, node anc set anc.tw = anc.tw - me.sz from 
node me, node anc where me.tw=18 and anc.tw >= me.tw;
```

Then we need to adjust the parent for those whose pa's tw is higher than the branch to be removed.

```
update node me, node anc set anc.pa = anc.pa - me.sz from 
node me, node anc where me.tw=18 and anc.pa >= me.tw;
```

Answer (score 7):

Well given the choice, I'd be using objects. I'd create an object for each record where each object has a `children` collection and store them all in an assoc array (/hashtable) where the Id is the key. And blitz through the collection once, adding the children to the relevant children fields. **Simple.**

But because you're being no fun by restricting use of some good OOP, I'd probably iterate based on:

```
function PrintLine(int pID, int level)
    foreach record where ParentID == pID
        print level*tabs + record-data
        PrintLine(record.ID, level + 1)

PrintLine(0, 0)
```

Edit: this is similar to a couple of other entries, but I think it's slightly cleaner. One thing I'll add: this is extremely SQL-intensive. It's *nasty*. **If you have the choice, go the OOP route.**

Comment: That is what I meant with "no frameworks" - you are using LINQ, aren't you? Regarding your first paragraph: The result set is already there, why copying all the info to a new object structure first? (I was not clear enough on that fact, sorry)

Comment: Tomalak - no the code is pseudo-code. Of course you'd have to break things out into proper selects and iterators... and a real syntax! Why OOP? Because you can exactly mirror the structure. It keeps things nice and it just happens to be more efficient (only one select)

Comment: I had no repeated selects in mind either. Regarding OOP: Mark Bessey said in his answer: "You can emulate any other data structure with a hashmap, so that's not a terrible limitation.". Your solution is correct, but I think there is some room fore improvement even without OOP.

Answer (score 5):

This was written quickly, and is neither pretty nor efficient (plus it autoboxes alot, converting between `int` and `Integer` is annoying!), but it works.

It probably breaks the rules since I'm creating my own objects but hey I'm doing this as a diversion from real work :)

This also assumes that the resultSet/table is completely read into some sort of structure before you start building Nodes, which wouldn't be the best solution if you have hundreds of thousands of rows.

```
public class Node {

    private Node parent = null;

    private List<Node> children;

    private String name;

    private int id = -1;

    public Node(Node parent, int id, String name) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return (this.parent == null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", parent=" + parent;
    }
}

public class NodeBuilder {

    public static Node build(List<Map<String, String>> input) {

        // maps id of a node to it's Node object
        Map<Integer, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();

        // maps id of a node to the id of it's parent
        Map<Integer, Integer> childParentMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        // create special 'root' Node with id=0
        Node root = new Node(null, 0, "root");
        nodeMap.put(root.getId(), root);

        // iterate thru the input
        for (Map<String, String> map : input) {

            // expect each Map to have keys for "id", "name", "parent" ... a
            // real implementation would read from a SQL object or resultset
            int id = Integer.parseInt(map.get("id"));
            String name = map.get("name");
            int parent = Integer.parseInt(map.get("parent"));

            Node node = new Node(null, id, name);
            nodeMap.put(id, node);

            childParentMap.put(id, parent);
        }

        // now that each Node is created, setup the child-parent relationships
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : childParentMap.entrySet()) {
            int nodeId = entry.getKey();
            int parentId = entry.getValue();

            Node child = nodeMap.get(nodeId);
            Node parent = nodeMap.get(parentId);
            parent.addChild(child);
        }

        return root;
    }
}

public class NodePrinter {

    static void printRootNode(Node root) {
        printNodes(root, 0);
    }

    static void printNodes(Node node, int indentLevel) {

        printNode(node, indentLevel);
        // recurse
        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            printNodes(child, indentLevel + 1);
        }
    }

    static void printNode(Node node, int indentLevel) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < indentLevel; i++) {
            sb.append("\t");
        }
        sb.append(node);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // setup dummy data
        List<Map<String, String>> resultSet = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        resultSet.add(newMap("1", "Node 1", "0"));
        resultSet.add(newMap("2", "Node 1.1", "1"));
        resultSet.add(newMap("3", "Node 2", "0"));
        resultSet.add(newMap("4", "Node 1.1.1", "2"));
        resultSet.add(newMap("5", "Node 2.1", "3"));
        resultSet.add(newMap("6", "Node 1.2", "1"));

        Node root = NodeBuilder.build(resultSet);
        printRootNode(root);

    }

    //convenience method for creating our dummy data
    private static Map<String, String> newMap(String id, String name, String parentId) {
        Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row.put("id", id);
        row.put("name", name);
        row.put("parent", parentId);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: I always find it hard to filter the algorithm-specific part from the implementation-specific part when presented with a lot of source code. That's why I asked for a solution that was not language-specific in the first place. But it does the job, so thanks for your time!

Comment: I see what you mean now, if it's not obvious the main algorithm is in NodeBuilder.build() - I probably could have done a better job of summing this up.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you know that the root elements are zero, here's the pseudocode to output to text:

```
function PrintLevel (int curr, int level)
    //print the indents
    for (i=1; i<=level; i++)
        print a tab
    print curr \n;
    for each child in the table with a parent of curr
        PrintLevel (child, level+1)


for each elementID where the parentid is zero
    PrintLevel(elementID, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate any other data structure with a hashmap, so that's not a terrible limitation.  Scanning from the top to the bottom, you create a hashmap for each row of the database, with an entry for each column. Add each of these hashmaps to a "master" hashmap, keyed on the id. If any node has a "parent" that you haven't seen yet, create an placeholder entry for it in the master hashmap, and fill it in when you see the actual node.

To print it out, do a simple depth-first pass through the data, keeping track of indent level along the way. You can make this easier by keeping a "children" entry for each row, and populating it as you scan the data.

As for whether there's a "better" way to store a tree in a database, that depends on how you're going to use the data. I've seen systems that had a known maximum depth that used a different table for each level in the hierarchy. That makes a lot of sense if the levels in the tree aren't quite equivalent after all (top level categories being different than the leaves).

Answer (score 1):

If nested hash maps or arrays can be created, then I can simply go down the table from the beginning and add each item to the nested array. I must trace each line to the root node in order to know which level in the nested array to insert into. I can employ memoization so that I do not need to look up the same parent over and over again.

Edit: I would read the entire table into an array first, so it will not query the DB repeatedly. Of course this won't be practical if your table is very large.

After the structure is built, I must do a depth first traverse through it and print out the HTML.

There's no better fundamental way to store this information using one table (I could be wrong though ;), and would love to see a better solution ). However, if you create a scheme to employ dynamically created db tables, then you opened up a whole new world at the sacrifice of simplicity, and the risk of SQL hell ;).

Comment: I'd rather not change the DB layout just because a new level of sub-nodes is needed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To Extend Bill's SQL solution you can basically do the same using a flat array.  Further more if your strings all have the same lenght and your maximum number of children are known (say in a binary tree) you can do it using a single string (character array).  If you have arbitrary number of children this complicates things a bit...  I would have to check my old notes to see what can be done.

Then, sacrificing a bit of memory, especially if your tree is sparse and/or unballanced, you can, with a bit of index math, access all the strings randomly by storing your tree, width first in the array like so (for a binary tree):

```
String[] nodeArray = [L0root, L1child1, L1child2, L2Child1, L2Child2, L2Child3, L2Child4] ...
```

yo know your string length, you know it

I'm at work now so cannot spend much time on it but with interest I can fetch a bit of code to do this.

We use to do it to search in binary trees made of DNA codons, a process built the tree, then we flattened it to search text patterns and when found, though index math (revers from above) we get the node back...  very fast and efficient, tough our tree rarely had empty nodes, but we could searh gigabytes of data in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-order transversal with on-the-fly path enumeration on adjacency representation**

Nested sets from:

- Konchog https://stackoverflow.com/a/42781302/895245
- Jonny Buchanan https://stackoverflow.com/a/194031/895245

is the only efficient way I've seen of traversing, at the cost of slower updates. That's likely what most people will want for pre-order.

Closure table from https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/895245 is interesting, but I don't see how to enforce pre-order there: [MySQL Closure Table hierarchical database - How to pull information out in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252323/mysql-closure-table-hierarchical-database-how-to-pull-information-out-in-the-c)

Mostly for fun, here's a method that recursively calculates the 1.3.2.5. prefixes on the fly and sorts by them at the end, based only on the parent ID/child index representation.

Upsides:

- updates only need to update the indexes of each sibling

Downsides:

- n^2 memory usage worst case for a super deep tree. This could be quite serious, which is why I say this method is likely mostly for fun only. But maybe there is some ultra high update case where someone would want to use it? Who knows
- recursive queries, so reads are going to be less efficient than nested sets

Create and populate table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ParentIndexTree" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "parentId" INTEGER,
  "childIndex" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "value" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ("parentId") REFERENCES "ParentIndexTree"(id)
)
;
INSERT INTO "ParentIndexTree" VALUES
  (0, NULL, 0, 1, 'one'  ),
  (1, 0,    0, 2, 'two'  ),
  (2, 0,    1, 3, 'three'),
  (3, 1,    0, 4, 'four' ),
  (4, 1,    1, 5, 'five' )
;
```

Represented tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \
4   5
```

Then for a DBMS with arrays like PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE "TreeSearch" (
  "id",
  "parentId",
  "childIndex",
  "value",
  "name",
  "prefix"
) AS (
  SELECT
    "id",
    "parentId",
    "childIndex",
    "value",
    "name",
    array[0]
  FROM "ParentIndexTree"
  WHERE "parentId" IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    "child"."id",
    "child"."parentId",
    "child"."childIndex",
    "child"."value",
    "child"."name",
    array_append("parent"."prefix", "child"."childIndex")
  FROM "ParentIndexTree" AS "child"
  JOIN "TreeSearch" AS "parent"
    ON "child"."parentId" = "parent"."id"
)
SELECT * FROM "TreeSearch"
ORDER BY "prefix"
;
```

This creates on the fly prefixes of form:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0, 0
3 -> 0, 1
4 -> 0, 0, 0
5 -> 0, 0, 1
```

and then PostgreSQL then sorts by the arrays alphabetically as:

```
1 -> 0
2 -> 0, 0
4 -> 0, 0, 0
5 -> 0, 0, 1
3 -> 0, 1
```

which is the pre-order result that we want.

For a DBMS without arrays like SQLite, you can hack by encoding the prefix with a string of fixed width integers. Binary would be ideal, but I couldn't find out how, so hex would work. This of course means you will have to select a maximum depth that will fit in the number of bytes selected, e.g. below I choose 6 allowing for a maximum of 16^6 children per node.

```
WITH RECURSIVE "TreeSearch" (
  "id",
  "parentId",
  "childIndex",
  "value",
  "name",
  "prefix"
) AS (
  SELECT
    "id",
    "parentId",
    "childIndex",
    "value",
    "name",
    '000000'
  FROM "ParentIndexTree"
  WHERE "parentId" IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    "child"."id",
    "child"."parentId",
    "child"."childIndex",
    "child"."value",
    "child"."name",
    "parent"."prefix" || printf('%06x', "child"."childIndex")
  FROM "ParentIndexTree" AS "child"
  JOIN "TreeSearch" AS "parent"
    ON "child"."parentId" = "parent"."id"
)
SELECT * FROM "TreeSearch"
ORDER BY "prefix"
;
```

**Some nested set notes**

Here are a few points which confused me a bit after looking at the other nested set answers.

Jonny Buchanan shows his nested set setup as:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|  Root 1                                                                  |
|   ________________________________    ________________________________   |
|  |  Child 1.1                     |  |  Child 1.2                     |  |
|  |   ___________    ___________   |  |   ___________    ___________   |  |
|  |  |  C 1.1.1  |  |  C 1.1.2  |  |  |  |  C 1.2.1  |  |  C 1.2.2  |  |  |
1  2  3___________4  5___________6  7  8  9___________10 11__________12 13 14
|  |________________________________|  |________________________________|  |
|__________________________________________________________________________|
```

which made me wonder why not just use the simpler looking:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
|  Root 1                                                                 |
|   ________________________________    _______________________________   |
|  |  Child 1.1                     |  |  Child 1.2                    |  |
|  |   ___________    ___________   |  |   ___________   ___________   |  |
|  |  |  C 1.1.1  |  |  C 1.1.2  |  |  |  |  C 1.2.1  | |  C 1.2.2  |  |  |
1  2  3___________|  4___________|  |  5  6___________| 7___________|  |  | 
|  |________________________________|  |_______________________________|  |
|_________________________________________________________________________|
```

which does not have an extra number for each endpoint.

But then when I actually tried to implement it, I noticed that it was hard/impossible to implement the update queries like that, unless I had parent information as used by Konchog. The problem is that it was hard/impossible to distinguish between a sibling and a parent in one case while the tree was being moved around, and I needed that to decide if I was going to reduce the right hand side or not while closing a gap.

Left/size vs left/right: you could store it either way in the database, but I think left/right can be more efficient as you can index the DB with a multicolumn index (left, right) which can then be used to speed up ancestor queries, which are of type:

```
left < curLeft AND right > curLeft
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, PostgreSQL 14.5, SQLite 3.34.0.

Answer (score 0):

If elements are in tree order, as shown in your example, you can use something like the following Python example:

```
delimiter = '.'
stack = []
for item in items:
  while stack and not item.startswith(stack[-1]+delimiter):
    print "</div>"
    stack.pop()
  print "<div>"
  print item
  stack.append(item)
```

What this does is maintain a stack representing the current position in the tree. For each element in the table, it pops stack elements (closing the matching divs) until it finds the parent of the current item. Then it outputs the start of that node and pushes it to the stack.

If you want to output the tree using indenting rather than nested elements, you can simply skip the print statements to print the divs, and print a number of spaces equal to some multiple of the size of the stack before each item. For example, in Python:

```
print "  " * len(stack)
```

You could also easily use this method to construct a set of nested lists or dictionaries.

Edit: I see from your clarification that the names were not intended to be node paths. That suggests an alternate approach:

```
idx = {}
idx[0] = []
for node in results:
  child_list = []
  idx[node.Id] = child_list
  idx[node.ParentId].append((node, child_list))
```

This constructs a tree of arrays of tuples(!). idx[0] represents the root(s) of the tree. Each element in an array is a 2-tuple consisting of the node itself and a list of all its children. Once constructed, you can hold on to idx[0] and discard idx, unless you want to access nodes by their ID.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using nosql tools like neo4j for hierarchial structures. 
e.g a networked application like linkedin uses couchbase (another nosql solution)

But use nosql only for data-mart level queries and not to store / maintain transactions

Comment: Having read of the complexities and perf of SQL and "non-table" structures, this was my first thought too, nosql. Of course, there are so many issues to exporting, etc.  Plus, the OP mentioned only tables. Oh well.  I'm not a DB expert, as is obvious.